# Undefined method flash when using Devise, Confirmable on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

I'm using Devise with the confirmable module on Rails 4.2. I've written a custom `ConfirmationsController` with `after_confirmation_path_for` of `/app/auth`. The basic scenario I'm testing is:

```
scenario 'A user can confirm their account by clicking a link in the email' do
  user = create(:user, email: 'bob@acme.com')
  open_email(user.email)

  expect(current_email.subject).to eq('Finish creating your account on Hourglass')

  current_email.click_link 'Create an account on Hourglass'

  expect(user.reload.confirmed_at).not_to be_nil
  expect(current_path).to eq('/app/auth')
end
```

which works. However, in production (the app is deployed on Heroku), I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `flash' for #<ActionDispatch::Request:0x007f68c8a29120>): 
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/flash.rb:9:in `flash' 
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.5.3/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb:153:in `set_flash_message' 
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.5.3/app/controllers/devise/confirmations_controller.rb:25:in `show'
```

which is [this line](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/3-stable/app/controllers/devise/confirmations_controller.rb#L25) in the `show` method of the default controller.

There's some other SO questions on how to solve this, but they are targeted towards rails-api apps; my app is a complete rails app.

I was able to "solve" this by adding the following config to my `application.rb`:

```
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Flash
```

but I'd like to (1) understand why this is happening in production only, and (2) have a spec to guarantee this functionality is working.

Comment: check your `config/environment/development.rb`, `config/environment/test.rb`, and `config/environment/production.rb` to see if `ActionDispatch::Flash` is being added/removed for a given environment.

Comment: nope, did a search for `::Flash` and only other place was `include Responders::FlashResponder` in `application_responder.rb`